# Is it even possible to run an ember 2.18 application in this decade?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, autoconf, watchman

I have to make some adjustments to the project done with ember 2.18.2, and it is a complete disaster right now.

I'm using macOS BigSur(11.6) and this is the pckage.json:

```
"body-parser": "^1.15.2",
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
"ember-ace": "1.3.2",
"ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
"ember-browserify": "^1.2.1",
"ember-changeset": "1.2.0",
"ember-changeset-validations": "1.2.4",
"ember-cli": "2.18.2",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^3.0.0",
"ember-cli-babel": "^6.6.0",
"ember-cli-clipboard": "0.13.0",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^2.0.0",
"ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.1",
"ember-cli-head": "^0.4.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.1",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.0",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
"ember-cli-markdown-editor": "^0.1.0",
"ember-cli-mirage": "0.2.9",
"ember-cli-moment-shim": "2.0.0",
"ember-cli-page-object": "1.8.0",
"ember-cli-qunit": "4.2.1",
"ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
"ember-cli-sentry": "3.0.0-beta.1",
"ember-cli-shims": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cli-spinner": "0.0.9",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-stylus": "1.0.6",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^2.0.0",
"ember-click-outside": "1.3.0",
"ember-data": "2.18.2",
"ember-data-has-many-query": "0.2.0",
"ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
"ember-file-upload": "^3.0.5",
"ember-font-awesome": "3.1.1",
"ember-inflector": "^3.0.1",
"ember-intercom-io": "0.1.4",
"ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
"ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "0.1.6",
"ember-metrics": "0.14.0",
"ember-modifier-manager-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
"ember-moment": "7.0.0-beta.3",
"ember-power-select": "1.10.4",
"ember-power-select-with-create": "0.4.0",
"ember-qunit": "3.3.0",
"ember-radio-buttons": "4.1.0",
"ember-resolver": "^4.0.0",
"ember-route-action-helper": "2.0.6",
```

As far as I understood I need watchman 4.9 for this project, which I tried to install from their git, by using something like this:

1. git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git (or download zip file from link above) ,
2. cd watchman ,
3. git checkout v4.6.0 ,
4. ./autogen.sh ,
5. ./configure ,
6. make ,
7. sudo make install

I can't install this version, since step 4 starts to break, and [the thread regarding the issue contains absolutely nothing](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/545).

I tried to use autoconf to compile it, but still, same errors as from the git issue above.

So my question is simple, can I run it?
Maybe avoid using watchman at all?

Comment: you dont need `watchman` for `ember-cli`, it will work without. `watchman` will only increase your rebuild speed.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting when you build? I ran into a similar problem to this and thought it was watchman too, but it isn't required.

The actual issue my node version. I fixed it by running `nvm use`, then `npm ci` in the project.

Comment: Watchman is not needed. I've never used it while developing Ember apps